# is it checking files in server side?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an application (http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Files/Files.php)

If you open the application, click on the "Add Question" button. This will add a table row. Now in the file input select a file which is invalid (like a .txt file for example).Now click on the "submit Details" button, it will state in an alert an "Unsupported file type" for question 1. Now go back to file input and change file to a valid format (.png, .jpg, .jpeg or .gif) and then after you have done that click on the "submit Details" button again, this time a confirmation box appears stating a message and if you want to proceed.

Now this all works fine on client side but what I want is that when the user clicks on the "Submit Details" button, I want it to check if the file format is correct in server side as well as client side for security purposes.

What I don know is that if the code below is checking for the file on server side as well as in client side because no message is appearing from an echo if wrong file is chosen after submission on the top corner.

Below is the php code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["imageFile"])) 
{ 

$allowedImageTypes = array("image/pjpeg","image/jpeg","image/jpg","image/png","image/x-png","image/gif");
$file = $_FILES['imageFile'];
$fileType = $file['type'];
if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedImageTypes)) { 
    echo "Unsupported file type";
}
else
{
    // Process the file
}
}
?>
```

Below is code on how the file input and question number is added in each row:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {   


    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");
    var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");


            var $imagefile = $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type: 'file',
            name: 'imageFile',
            class: 'imageFile'
        });

        $image.append($imagefile);

            var $imageclear = $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type: 'button',
            name: 'imageClear',
            class: 'imageClear',
            value: 'Clear File'
        });

        $image.append($imageclear);


    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($image);   
    $tbody.append($tr); 

}
```

Below is the table where the table rows are added into:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >


<div id="details">
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="image">Image</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form type should be

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="userfile" />
```

original name of the file on the client machine.

```
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

mime type of the file,

```
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']
```

size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

```
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']
```

temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

So

```
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedImageTypes)) { 
    echo "Unsupported file type";
}
else
{
    // Process the file
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you know for the form action, does it have to be uploader.php? I want the message to be displayed on the same page, also in my edit I included the code on how the data is added in the table.

Comment: if you write a separate page it will be better as it will prevent, refresh problem.

Comment: So is there a way where I can write the php on a seperate page but do not navigate to that page at all? I don't want the user to see the uploader.php file but I like the server to do a check on the background to see if it is correct file. The client side alert I have at moment will alert user if file type is correct or not. I just want to do a check on server side as well to be on safe side

Comment: Uploader page will only contain the whatever function u want to execute, it will not redirect to anything, dont put any HTML in it . Only database things you want to do.